# How to describe tags for rds snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

is there any possibility to describe tags for rds snapshots?

for ec2 instances I using:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Name,Values= --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId}'
```

but for rds snapshots I can not find any properly command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, tags are not included in the snapshot data as part of the `rds:DescribeDbSnapshots` API command. Instead, you would use the `rds:ListTagsForResource` API command. As part of the command, you would specify the ARN of the snapshot you are interested in.

Using the AWS CLI, that would look like this:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --resource-name arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:<account>:snapshot:rds:<snapshot-id>
```

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/list-tags-for-resource.html

**Update after comments**

Since `describe-db-snapshots` does not support filtering, you cannot filter the results based on tags. Instead, you must do the following:

1. Use `describe-db-snapshots` to get a complete list of snapshots.
2. For each snapshot returned, use `list-tags-for-resource` to get the tags. You can use the `--query` parameter to limit the results of the tags.
3. Conditionally, based on the results from `list-tags-for-resource` include or exclude your snapshot from your list of snapshots you care about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still I don't know how to using it properly to list environments with a specific tag. When I use - aws rds describe-db-snapshots --snapshot-type manual I see necessary informations, but I need snapshots only with a specific tags :/ but probably allows it only --filters option which is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the AWS CLI documentation for the RDS command, you'll notice (in section for [`describe-db-snapshots`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-snapshots.html) subcommand):

> `--filters (list)`
>
> > This parameter is not currently supported.

You'll be able to pipe the output without filters to a custom script, and filter there.